# jenkins-cli not authenticating with provided ssh private key

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

[Help]

Description of Problem
jenkins-cli not authenticating with provided ssh private key

Observed

when passing the jenkins-cli command:

```
java -jar ~/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 -i ~/.ssh/ccdevops who-am-i
```

The console output is:

> Authenticated as: anonymous
>
> Authorities:

Desired

Jenkins should authenticate as the user with the matching public key in their profile

Relevant Information

- jenkins v 2.46.3 and using the correct cli jar for the version
- Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-78-generic x86_64)
- only using recommend plugins
- running on azure cloud in china east datacenter
- azure network security group for the vm is configured to allow traffic
- ssh key being used was created on the ubuntu machine jenkins is running on and the public key is in the users entry in the jenkins user database
- Key was created using the instructions on the github site
- jenkins-cli is running on the server and not from a remote host

Steps Tried Already

- tried different keys with and without passphrases
- tried the web address with localhost and the ip address
- tried other jenkins-cli commands with same result
- tried to create other users and putting an public ssh key in their profile. (no duplicate keys between users)
- tried moving the location of the jenkins-cli jar from server root to jenkins home directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also specify the SSH method and the user on the command line with `-ssh` and `-user USER_NAME` respectively.  After that, your command would look like this:

`java -jar ~/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 -i ~/.ssh/ccdevops who-am-i -ssh -user USER_NAME`

Also note that you'll need to be able to access the server via SSH as well.